# Pasar formato Date yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a 12h

Tags: ios, swift, date

Tengo este formato y obviamente cuando activo el reloj a 12h me devuelve un `null` , si lo pongo a 24h me formatea bien la fecha.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?
!
Update:
Para el 12h intento esto

```
let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter1.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") as TimeZone!
        print(dateFormatter1.date(from: "2017-01-1 14:55:08")) //if you want current date
```

Y esto me devuelve un nulo

El problema reside aqui.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya he updateado la prgunta

Answer (score 2):

**EDITADA**
Prueba cambiando las h:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
```

lo que te da el formato de 12h o de 24h son las H.

> ```
> HH --> 24h 
>
> hh --> 12h  
>
> a --> Añade AM o PM al final
> ```

**Vuelvo a editar**

Según reviso en tu edición, tratas de crear una fecha a partir de un String.

Tu String `"2017-02-1 14:55:08"` tiene formato `yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss`
Si lo que quieres es pasar esa hora a formato 12h deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
var date = Date()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss"
date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-02-1 14:55:08")!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-d hh:mm:ss"
let stringdate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
let newDate12h = dateFormatter.date(from: stringdate)
```

Comment: He updateado mi rpegunta , lo probé así pero no funcionó

Comment: @Alejandro fijate que el tiene puesto `hh` en minusculas lo que hace que sea hasta `12` en vez de `24` (mira esta pagina: http://nsdateformatter.com/)

Comment: he editado la respuesta, gracias @lois6b

Comment: sisi haha se lo decia a alejandro, ^^ (edite mi comentario) En verdad te me adelantaste porque esperaba a publicar mi respuesta cuando él pusiera que intentó para 12h. +1

Comment: He probado como tu dices y sigue fallandome , es por que no viene am o pm en el string ?

Comment: Acabo de ver que tu formato de hora no es ese, sería "yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss" 

Si intentas crear una fecha desde un String el formato no puede ser de 12 horas.

Comment: Voy a probar tu ejemplo

Comment: Me da un error por que en la 4 linea esta forzando a que no sea opcional con el '!' , pero si no lo pones no deja compilar , lo probastes?

Comment: Lo probé en playground y me funcionó. Quizá si lo estás probando con el string recibido del servidor y esa variable es opcional a lo mejor puede ser q ahí se genere el conflicto. ¿Si lo rodeas de un try/catch o de un guard?

Answer (score 1):

El problema se solucionó añadiendo esto :

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier:"es_ES")
```